# Entity Class with an Id nested in a different Entity Class

Tags: java, hibernate

I got a database table MyTable with those columns:
int Id, String Type, String Value

and I got an entity Class with those fields

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
class MyClass {
    @Id
    int Id;
    String Type;
    String Value;
}
```

Now what I want are Classes that look like that:

```
@Entity
class TypeA {
    MyClass myClass;
    //some stuff
}
```

The Id of TypeA should be MyClass.Id. Can this be done with Hibernate? MyClass has to be a variable of TypeA, I explicitly do not want any inheritance.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `class TypaA extends MyClass` then you inherit the id that you need. Note: just seen 'I explicitly do not want any inheritance'. Why?

Comment: Using `Embeddable` and `Embedded` annotations will solve your problem. Use `Embeddable` on `MyClass` and `Embedded` on `TypeA` class. But with one caveat, i.e., you should move `id` field from `MyClass` to the `TypeA` class. That is the close you can get, I think.

Comment: @Fubar It basically boils down "design decision".

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can see and comes close to your requirement but with one caveat is:

Using annotations `Embeddable` on `MyClass` and `Embedded` on `TypeA` will solve your problem partially.

Partially because of the caveat, i.e., you should move `id` field from `MyClass` to the `TypeA` class. That is the close you can get without using inheritance, I think.

Would be interested to see if there really exists any solution that meets your requirement exactly.

Anyways, if inheritance is an option, that would allow you to have `id` in the super class and have this super class annotated as `MappedSuperClass` and let `TypeA` extend super class.